# Conversion to NS_ENUM from typedef enum leads to duplicate symbols

Tags: objective-c, enums

With this definition:

```
typedef enum {
    FormTypeLong,
    FormTypeShort
} FormType
```

I can use `FormType` in my code the following ways:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) FormType formType; 

- (void)getFormTypeUsed:(void (^)(FormType formType)) completion;

-(FormType)getDefaultFormType;

-(void)setFormType: (FormType) type;

...
FormType formType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:FormTypeLog];
```

However changing the `typedef enum` to

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FormType) {
    FormTypeLong,
    FormTypeShort
}
```

Causes Xcode to say that I must use `enum` tag to refer to type `FormType` and subsequently throughout the code, to place the tag in front of all uses of FormType.

After doing this, I get an error saying I have duplicate symbols.

How am I supposed to convert to NS_ENUM without all these errors?

Comment: You missed off the `typedef` before `NS_ENUM`.

Comment: completely missed that. Thanks @trojanfoe

Comment: @trojanfoe you should add an answer, not sure if there's another SO question that covers this scenario.

Comment: @Cristik OK done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `typedef` before `NS_ENUM`.